# Remove Specific Shapes from the Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Hy, I have an excel workbook consisting an Excel Sheet which contains images, shapes, arrows and many more shapes. The structure of the sheet looks like this.
[image]

[image]
In the above picture, I circle all the textboxes, arrows, Ovels, shapes which I want to delete. I have written a code to delete text boxes which are checking the existence of textboxes and if found delete them. In the other hand, if not exist show pop-up that text-box, does not exist. The code is as under.

```
    Sub resetall()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim arow As Shapes
Dim txtbox As TextBox
Set ws = ActiveSheet
If ws.TextBoxes.Count < 0 Then
MsgBox "No Text Box Exist."
Exit Sub
End If
ws.TextBoxes.Delete
MsgBox "Text Box has been deleted successfully."
End Sub
```

This code is working fine, but I could not find the code for Arrows, and Oval Shapes, and Circles. Please check my code and guide me. I tried to use the shapes. Oval reference from the library but could not succeed. Please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want skipping any shape type, or do you want deleting all existing ones?

Comment: @FaneDuru    Yes I want to skip rectangle as those are, I am using as buttons.

Comment: @FaneDuru Deleteall shapes macro I know it is working but it delete all the shapes but i want to more specific as per diagram above. thanks

Comment: Then, try the code I posted...

Comment: @shakeelahmad: Did you read my comment ("Optionally, add a test inside the loop for a specific type...") at the end of my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub DeleteallShapesExceptRect()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, s As Shape, boolRect As Boolean

 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 For Each s In ws.Shapes
    If s.Type = msoAutoShape Then
        If s.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangle Then
           boolRect = True
        End If
    End If
    If Not boolRect Then s.Delete
    boolRect = False
Next
```

The next variant excepts any Rectangle shape type:

```
Sub DeleteallShapesExceptAllRect()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, s As Shape, boolRect As Boolean

 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 For Each s In ws.Shapes
    If s.Type = msoAutoShape Then
        If s.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangle Or _
                msoShapeRoundedRectangle Or msoShapeRound1Rectangle Or _
                                        msoShapeSnip2DiagRectangle Then
           boolRect = True
        End If
    End If
    If Not boolRect Then s.Delete
    boolRect = False
 Next
End Sub
```

The following variant deletes all shapes from a specific range:

```
Sub DeleteAllShapesOnRange()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, s As Shape, rngDel As Range

 Set ws = ActiveSheet: Set rngDel = ws.Range("A1:W6")
 For Each s In ws.Shapes
    If Not Intersect(rngDel, s.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
        s.Delete
    End If
 Next
End Sub
```

And the next one deletes all shapes which are **Not** on the specific range:

```
Sub DeleteAllShapesNotOnRange()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, s As Shape, rngNoDel As Range, boolFound As Boolean

 Set ws = ActiveSheet: Set rngNoDel = ws.Range("A1:W6")
 For Each s In ws.Shapes
    If Not Intersect(rngNoDel, s.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
        boolFound = True
    End If
    If Not boolFound Then s.Delete
 Next
End Sub
```

And finally, a version deleting all shapes not having text:

```
Sub DeleteAllShapesNotHavingText()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, s As Shape, boolFound As Boolean

 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 For Each s In ws.Shapes
    If Not Len(s.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text) = 0 Then
        boolFound = True
    End If
    If Not boolFound Then s.Delete
 Next
End Sub
```

***Note:*** Each such a code is able to ask for permission before deletion, but it will not make big difference between the manual deletion and the one done in code... If you insist to have such a condition, please specify which of the above versions to be adapted.

Anyhow, the next `Sub` returns (in Immediate Window) all (mentioned) shapes type. You can change their names. The following code check their real type, which is returned like `Long`:

```
Sub EnumerateShapesType()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, s As Shape, boolRect As Boolean, arrS As Variant, arrEl As Variant, El As Variant
 arrS = Split("Rectangle|1,Round Rectangle|5,Oval|9,Right Arrow|33,Down Arrow|36", ",")

 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 For Each s In ws.Shapes
    If s.Type = msoAutoShape Then
        For Each El In arrS
            If s.AutoShapeType = Split(El, "|")(1) Then
                Debug.Print s.Name, Split(El, "|")(0): Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I think it is possible to correct the sub name!

Comment: @Dang D. Khanh: What do you mean? What name to correct? The above code one? If yes, doesn't it reflect what it does?

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru, may be DeleteallShapesExceptRect.

Comment: @FaneDuru Hi, I used this code, but its work like delete everything as above code. It is not exempted the RoundedRectangle Shapes. I changed it from Rectangle to Rounded Rectangle shape. But it is deleting all the shapes. Why not we used check like I used either the text box exists or not, I want to track only Arrows (With Direction Arrow any direction), Oval shaps, Rectangles, Squares, Is it possible first we make check either the relevant shape exist or not on the sheet? then we delete it. I hope you understand what I am taking about.

Comment: I have added a new picture, all the buttons should not be deleted as I mark the naming convention of buttons. While all the other circles within the sheet should be considered as deleted shapes. I want to delete them only. Is it possible we can  delete all the shape within a specific range?

Comment: Yes, it is! Please define the range. I am referring to your last question. Otrerwisw, I cannot understand how the rectangles are deleted...

Comment: @Dang D. Khanh: Upss... I could swear that I wrote 'Shape`. Even after your comment... Thanks! I will edit and adapt it...

Comment: @shakeel ahmad: Which variant? I tried offering all possible solutions...

Answer (score 2):

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/vba-delete-all-shapes

```
Sub DeleteAllShapes()
'PURPOSE: Remove All Shape Objects From The Active Worksheet
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

Dim shp As Shape

For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
   shp.Delete
Next shp

End Sub
```

Optionally, add a test inside the loop for a specific type from [msoShapeType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoshapetype)

Comment: I have already tested this code but it deletes all the shapes including my button, that why I am trying to make more custom code.

Comment: @shakeelahmad consider adding an `if` condition to prevent the deletion of your button. You should be able to identified them by their name

Answer (score 1):

Office 365 answer:

- Go to the Home tab
- Go to Find & Select
- Go to Selection Pane

You now have the names of the shapes in your worksheet.

As an example, you could use `ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Straight Arrow Connector 1")).Delete` to remove a single item.